# Use maven-archetype-nar-exec to generate project

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am brand new to Maven.

How can I create the [`maven-archetype-nar-exec`](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/archetypes.html) project type?

If I run `mvn -archetype=generate` I do not get the option to select `maven-archetype-nar-exec`?

Do I have to download something into the Maven repository?

I'm using `Maven 3.0.3`

Comment: filed as bug: https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/issues/145

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you issue to see a list of available archetypes is `mvn archetype:generate`.  However that doesn't list the **Nar plugin**.  This is [apparently because](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-nar-plugin-td4343006.html) it isn't available in the [Maven central repository](http://repo1.maven.org).  The [recommendation](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-nar-plugin-td4343006.html) seems to be to install it from source.

Comment: I followed one of the links (from the links you gave me) and found it [here](http://java.freehep.org/maven2/org/freehep/freehep-nar-plugin/).  Can I add that repository to my maven lookup when running `mvn -archetype:generate`?

Comment: You can tell Maven the repositories it must consult in the settings file (See http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories).  Don't forget any proxy settings (http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) that may be needed.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/1373572) is my settings file.  I can't get NAR to show up?

Comment: I changed my settings file on the GIST above and the following came out on the terminal: `Downloading: http://java.freehep.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml` but nothing to do with `org/freehep/...`?  This is so frustrating...:(

Comment: Yes, I was about to tell you to include `pluginRepository` and **not** `repository` in this case.  However, the underlying issue is that the location **does not exist**.  You can confirm this by pointing your browser to the same URL.  This was pointed out in the discussion I referenced in my original response (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-nar-plugin-td4343006.html).  Hence the need to build from source.

Comment: right I think I have set it up correctly.  I've managed to add the repo to the `settings.xml` and have a `pom.xml` that can reference `<packaging>nar</packaging>`.  I _still_ cannot see `org/freehep/freehep_nar_plugin` when i run `mvn archetype:generate`.  Sorry for all the comments - I just _really_ want to get to the point where I can generate a new NAR project and compile!!

Comment: I understand your frustration.  However the answer is **not** at java.freehp.org.  The plugin **IS NOT THERE**.  Apparently the only way to get the plugin is by downloading the source and building and installing it to your local repository.  **Then** `mvn archetype:generate` will list that plugin's archetype as an option.

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks for all your help - you're very kind :)  I need to role this new build system out over the whole company, so a little worried no-one is going to know what to do.  I think the best thing would be to create a common repository for the company.

Comment: You are quite welcome.  Coming up-to-speed can be an ordeal mainly because Maven does quite a few things for you (as opposed to _you_ having to tell the build system).  However for a newbie it can seem like black-magic.  Having to build from source is not ideal but sometimes that's the best of a worst situation.  Creating a company-wide (regional) repository is a good idea.  We do that.  You can also look into tools like Artifactory (http://www.jfrog.com/products.php).

Comment: It appears `maven-nar-plugin` is now available in Maven Central under `org.codeswarm:maven-nar-plugin`

Answer (score 5):

As Sri Sankaran already pointed out, these archetypes aren't included in any of the public or official repositories currently. The following Recipe worked for me

1. get the maven source projects for the Archetypes. Note: there is a separate project for each Archetype. Here I'll show the **archetype-nar-exec** as an example

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/duns/maven-archetype-nar-exec.git
   ```
2. build and install the archetype(s) into your local repository

   ```
   cd maven-archetype-nar-exec
   mvn clean install
   ```
3. create a *local archetype catalog* just for use right now

   ```
   Example file: localCatalog.xml

   <archetype-catalog  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd">
   <archetypes>
       <archetype>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetypes</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-archetype-nar-exec</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <repository>snapshots</repository>
           <description>Maven project to build a simple C/C++ executable</description>
       </archetype>

       <!-- ... add here further archetypes if you like -->

      </archetypes>
   </archetype-catalog>
   ```

   probably you'll need to adjust the version and the repository ID (or URL) to point to your local repository
4. invoke the maven archetype-plugin and point it at our local catalog file:

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://./localCatalog.xml
   ```

   the rest should work interactively